# How to rotate an image using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Well, this seems to be easy, but I have been hours trying to do this. 
I'm trying to develop a circular control, with an image and rotate the control, just like sound volume control of the big sound equipment. Then to rotate the image, I use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `ATAN2`.

Using the center of the image like 0,0 coordinates, and the origin and the size of the image to measure my action area. After calculate the angle with the X and Y from the center of the image (my 0,0). If the Touch is out of the boundaries of the image, do nothing, but if is inside the image, I want rotate it, but, still no working. 
EDIT: I don't want to use two fingers in this procedure, I need to use just one finger.

UIRotateGestureRecognizer uses two and can take that way here.

Here is my code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myMainIndicatorRoulett;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanWithGestureRecognizer:)];
        [self.myTestView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

        _myMainIndicatorRoulett.image = [TheColoristImages imageOfColorIndicatorWithIndicatorAngle:(CGFloat)90.0];

    }



-(void)handlePanWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
    {
        double a1;
        double a2;

        a1 = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x;
        a2 = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].y;

        double b1;
        double b2;

        b1 = _myMainIndicatorRoulett.frame.origin.x;
        b2 = _myMainIndicatorRoulett.frame.origin.y;

        double c1;
        double c2;

        c1 = b1 + _myMainIndicatorRoulett.frame.size.width;
        c2 = b2 + _myMainIndicatorRoulett.frame.size.height;

        if ((a1 > b1) && (a1 < c1) && (a2 > b2) && (a2 < c2))
        {
            double Cx;
            double Cy;
            Cx = _myMainIndicatorRoulett.center.x;
            Cy = _myMainIndicatorRoulett.center.y;

            double Tx;
            double Ty;
            Tx = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x - Cx;
            Ty = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].y - Cy;
            double myAngle = atan2(Ty, Tx);

            _myMainIndicatorRoulett.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_myMainIndicatorRoulett.transform, myAngle * 3.14 / 180);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`? That would make things much simple.

Comment: What I want to do is a rotation procedure with one finger not two to use the iPhone with one hand. For other thing use two fingers woukd be the easy way but here it's better just one and that is why I'm struggling so much. Do you have any idea for this???

Comment: Explain what your code does wrong.

Comment: Sure @Wain, I want to rotate the image with just ine finger and rotate it in the same way a slide my finger on the screen but whe I try, the image rotate extremely fast, or to slowly or just rotate ina the half and just that... or worse

Comment: Initially, log the Tx and Ty values, and the angle you calculate from them. Then you can see if you have a normalisation problem or a scale problem (or both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the last line:

```
_myMainIndicatorRoulett.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_myMainIndicatorRoulett.transform, myAngle * 3.14 / 180);
```

When you use CGAffineTransformRotate(s, a), it adds that angle, doesn't set it. That's why it's going crazy. Every time you call that function it adds "myAngle" degrees to the rotation, making it look like it's spinning. You want to set the angle.

You want to use this:

```
_myMainIndicatorRoulett.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(myAngle);
```

Comment: I did not understand the difference, and now works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

One finger rotatation on UIView: https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer
Check this repo, it is a customized gestureRecognizer that handle the one-finger rotation for you.